Do I need to get a second BS or an MS to get into mechanical engineering?
I have a BA in math, working in an unrelated career field.
If I want to get into the mechanical engineering field, is it better to get a second Bachelors in MechE or an MS in MechE? There are programs that will accept me for a MS and make me do a few undergrad prerequisites; however, I'm concerned that the lack of an ABET accredited BS will hold me back in the job market. On the other hand, in my state (Rhode Island) I would be able to get my PE with just the MS and math degree.

Please [edit] to include your location. The answer may depend on that.

Edited to include state.

I meant country, - you're on an international site - but I know where Rhode Island is.

duplicated here: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/199945/75821

In my experience, for the most part people tend to look at your most recent educational experience and mostly ignore what came before that.
For example, when applying to college your high-school grades are important but middle school isn't; or when applying to a Master's, your Bachelor's grades are scrutinized but your High-school isn't.
By that logic, I would think achieving an MS in MechEng would be adequate.  As you said, all the theoretical holes would be filled by the MS requiring any missing BS-level courses. (In addition your maturity and age will often enable you to learn faster and more efficiently than during undergrad.)
The only thing i could imagine a potential employer wondering about is whether you have less total time experience due to doing a shorter MS versus the potentially longer BS. (For example, an ME undergrad may have spent 3 years playing with Solidworks, versus only 1 year to get an MS - just a guess).
So you may want to tackle that potential concern by ensuring your résumé shows that you have enough experience by the end of the MS program.  For example, by showing fairly complex projects completed during your MS, or better yet, internships in ME type of positions, in which you gained experience using the tools of the trade for significant amounts of time (eg. 2-3mo. or more).
